# spring boot to enable SSL with certificate from the authority

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl

I have a quick question about enabling SSL in the spring boot application. I have a SSL certificate that I received from the system team. The certificated was created through the third-party Certificate authority. Our current application is just based on spring-boot which listens on port 80. I am trying to enable SSL in the spring boot application, but all the tutorials/examples are about using self-signed certificate with the following configuration.

```
server.port=80
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=src/main/resources/keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=****
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
```

Is it because spring boot doesn't support this type certificate?  BTW, I don't have a password that was used for creating a certificate.

I received only cert and key files.

Is there a way to enable SSL in the spring boot with this type of certificate or do I need to use http server and have it redirect to spring boot?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot expects a keystore containing your certificate, not the certificate alone. You can create the keystore with the command:

```
keytool -import -alias mycert -file myCertificate.crt -keystore keystore.p12 -storepass password
```

This will create the keystore file 'keystore.p12' containing your certificate protected by password 'password'.

Comment: can I use any password?